# DecimalFromat Issues, mainly for 2 digits after the decimal

Tags: java, eclipse-neon

This is my code:

```
public class TemperatureConverter {
public static float convertTemp1 (float temperature,
    char convertTo) {
    return convertTo;}
    public static String convertTemp (float temperature, char convertTo) {

     if (convertTo=='F'){
     return "The temperature in Fahrenheit is " + (9*temperature/5 + 32);
    } else if(convertTo=='C') {
     return "The temperature in Celsius is " + (temperature - 32) * 5/9;
    }  else{
     return "You can enter either F or C as convertTo argument";

}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Converting 21C to Fahrenheit. " +  convertTemp(21,'F', 0));
System.out.println("Converting 70F to Celsius. " + convertTemp(70,'C', 0));
}
}
```

This is the output when your run it:

Converting 21C to Fahrenheit. The temperature in Fahrenheit is 69.8

Converting 70F to Celsius. The temperature in Celsius is 21.11111

I have been trying again, and again to make tje 2.11111, to 2.11, only 2 digits after the decimal point. May someone help me get from this:

Converting 21C to Fahrenheit. The temperature in Fahrenheit is 69.8

Converting 70F to Celsius. The temperature in Celsius is 21.11111

To this:

Converting 21C to Fahrenheit. The temperature in Fahrenheit is 69.8

Converting 70F to Celsius. The temperature in Celsius is 21.11

Comment: Also consider having a look at [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and [Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) to specify how many digits should be shown after the decimal point:

```
class Main {
  public static String convertTemp (float temperature, char convertTo) {
    if (convertTo == 'F') {
      return String.format("The temperature in Fahrenheit is %.1f", (9*temperature/5 + 32)); 
    } else if (convertTo == 'C') {
      return String.format("The temperature in Celsius is %.2f", (temperature - 32) * 5/9); 
    } else {
      return "You can enter either F or C as convertTo argument";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Converting 21C to Fahrenheit. " +  convertTemp(21,'F'));
    System.out.println("Converting 70F to Celsius. " + convertTemp(70,'C'));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Converting 21C to Fahrenheit. The temperature in Fahrenheit is 69.8
Converting 70F to Celsius. The temperature in Celsius is 21.11
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FFnK/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
    float temp = .....F;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0#");
    String formatedString = df.format(temp);

    System.out.println("temp: " + formatedString);
```

Input: 69.888888 > Output: "temp: 69.89"

Input: 69.8 > Output: "temp: 69.8"

In your example you left out the trailing zero with 69.8, if you want to have more or less trailing zeros just change # to 0 or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `String.format()`. For example:

```
  public class T {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", 10.12312));
  }
}
```